# Can't open TOOL GALLERIES Illustrator CC on second monitor

Tags: adobe

I have a laptop and a second display (via HDMI). In Illustrator CC, trial version, I can't open the flyout menus(known also as the 'tool galleries').
I know how they work, but nothing seems to do the trick (click and hold, right click, click on the corner). When I drag Illustrator back on the laptop display, the functionality reappears, the flyout menus work, but I need to use the second monitor.

Is this a bug? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have exactly the same issue but I have two monitors and this happens when Illustrator is open on my 'second' monitor.

A work-around is to make the monitor you wish to use Illustrator with your 'primary' monitor in settings (in Windows 8 right click on desktop - screen resolution) - this would be your HDMI display.